# Alertdialog with Gridview(Imageadpater)

Tags: android, gridview, android-alertdialog

Code in Activity:

```
  public void iconSelector(View view) {
    CoordinatorLayout coordinatorLayout = (CoordinatorLayout) findViewById(R.id.create_coordinator);
    LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
    View dialogView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_icon_grid_layout, coordinatorLayout, false);


    GridView gridView = (GridView) dialogView.findViewById(R.id.itemIconGridLayout);
    database = new Database(this);
    mId = database.getLastIdOD();
    if(mId>=1) {
        iconList = database.getIconList();

    }
    database.close();
    gridView.setAdapter(new IconsAdapter(getApplicationContext(),iconList));
    gridView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                                int position, long id) {
            mIcon = iconList.get(position).getName();
        }
    });

    AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
    builder.setView(dialogView);
    builder.setTitle(R.string.iconChoose);
    mIconSelectorDialog= builder.show();
}
```

Code in IconsAdapter:

```
    public class IconsAdapter extends BaseAdapter {
  private Context mContext;
List<Icon> iconList;

public IconsAdapter(Context context,List<Icon> list ){
    mContext = context;
    iconList = list;
    int d = iconList.size();
    String i= ""+d;
    Log.d("MyLogIconAdapter",iconList.get(0).getName());
    Log.d("MyLog",i);
}

public int getCount() {
    return iconList.size();

}

public Object getItem(int position) {
    return iconList.get(position).getId();
}

public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
}


@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    View grid;
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    if (convertView == null) {
        grid = new View(mContext);
        grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_icon_grid,null);
        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.imageItemIconGrid);
        int iconResId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(iconList.get(position).getName(), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
        imageView.setImageResource(iconResId);
    } else {
        grid = (View) convertView;
    }


    return grid;
}
```

}

Item_icon_grid:

```
<ImageView
    android:id="@+id/imageItemIconGrid"
    android:src="@drawable/ic_drafts_white_24dp"
    android:layout_width="18dp"
    android:layout_height="18dp"
    android:layout_gravity="center" />
```

item_icon_grid_layout:

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/itemIconGridLayout"
    android:numColumns="auto_fit"
    android:background="#ffffff"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="5dp"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">
</GridView>
```

Log:

> FATAL EXCEPTION: main
>                                                                                     Process: com.universe.time.officereminder, PID: 25213
>                                                                                     java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void
>   android.widget.ImageView.setImageResource(int)' on a null object
>   reference
>                                                                                         at
>   com.universe.time.proffesionaldiary.adapters.IconsAdapter.getView(IconsAdapter.java:60)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.AbsListView.obtainView(AbsListView.java:2828)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.GridView.onMeasure(GridView.java:1064)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.support.v7.widget.ContentFrameLayout.onMeasure(ContentFrameLayout.java:135)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.widget.LinearLayout.measureChildBeforeLayout(LinearLayout.java:1435)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.measureVertical(LinearLayout.java:721)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.LinearLayout.onMeasure(LinearLayout.java:612)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewGroup.measureChildWithMargins(ViewGroup.java:5832)
>                                                                                         at android.widget.FrameLayout.onMeasure(FrameLayout.java:430)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.onMeasure(PhoneWindow.java:3012)
>                                                                                         at android.view.View.measure(View.java:18647)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performMeasure(ViewRootImpl.java:2298)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.measureHierarchy(ViewRootImpl.java:1320)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.performTraversals(ViewRootImpl.java:1588)
>                                                                                         at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doTraversal(ViewRootImpl.java:1230)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.ViewRootImpl$TraversalRunnable.run(ViewRootImpl.java:6748)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.Choreographer$CallbackRecord.run(Choreographer.java:777)
>                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doCallbacks(Choreographer.java:590)
>                                                                                         at android.view.Choreographer.doFrame(Choreographer.java:560)
>                                                                                         at
>   android.view.Choreographer$FrameDisplayEventReceiver.run(Choreographer.java:763)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
>                                                                                         at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:145)
>                                                                                         at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6126)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
>                                                                                         at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
>                                                                                         at
>   com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:1399)
>                                                                                         at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1194)

Comment: from your adapter you are getting null images at the time of setImageResources

Comment: Possible duplicate of [What is a Null Pointer Exception, and how do I fix it?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/218384/what-is-a-null-pointer-exception-and-how-do-i-fix-it)

Answer (score 1):

You can try the following code, it may helpful.

```
    @Override
    public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        View grid = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item_icon_grid, null);

        if (convertView == null) {
            ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.imageItemIconGrid);
            int iconResId = mContext.getResources().getIdentifier(iconList.get(position).getName(), "drawable", mContext.getPackageName());
            imageView.setImageResource(iconResId);
        } else {
            grid = (View) convertView;
        }
        return grid;
    }
```

Reference: https://www.caveofprogramming.com/guest-posts/custom-gridview-with-imageview-and-textview-in-android.html

Answer (score 0):

error clearly suggest that you are trying to set image in `null` image view so check

`ImageView imageView = (ImageView) grid.findViewById(R.id.imageItemIconGrid)`;

is image view is part of your gridlayout if yes than check id for grid layout and for imageview if it is right or not .

please debug and check.